# Listview change icon when cell is clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a mastedetailpage and to fill the menu with text and icons i use a listview, i can show the the title and icons, I want when a person clicks in specific cell in the listview and the cell is select i want the icon to change, how can i do this?

I already tried  using two images , one for select icon and other for the unselect icon, but i dont know when the cell is deselected, the listview doesnt have that event.

Thanks.

MasterDetailPage:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Cantina2.ViewModels;assembly=Cantina2"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
         x:Class="test2.ViewModels.Views.Menu" Title="Menu1" >
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Icon="hamburger.png" Title="Menu"  BackgroundColor="White">
        <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <viewModels:MenuViewModel></viewModels:MenuViewModel>
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <!--left, top, right, bottom-->
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#01426A" HeightRequest="130">
                <controls:CircleImage x:Name="CircleImage" Source="{Binding fotoProf}" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  FillColor="Transparent" Margin="15,10,0,0">
                    <controls:CircleImage.WidthRequest>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <On Platform="Android, iOS">55</On>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </controls:CircleImage.WidthRequest>
                    <controls:CircleImage.HeightRequest>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <On Platform="Android, iOS">55</On>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </controls:CircleImage.HeightRequest>
                    <!--<controls:CircleImage.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                    </controls:CircleImage.GestureRecognizers>-->
                </controls:CircleImage>
                <Label Text="{Binding NomeColaborador}" Margin="15,10,0,0" TextColor="White">
                    <Label.FontSize>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <On Platform="iOS">12</On>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontSize>
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans-Semibold"/>
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="Calibri.ttf#Calibri"/>
                            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets\Fonts\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf#Open Sans"/>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding UsernameFormated}" Margin="15,-5,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#597CBE" IsVisible="True" Opacity="0.50">
                    <Label.FontSize>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <On Platform="iOS">12</On>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontSize>
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans-Semibold"/>
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="Calibri.ttf#Calibri"/>
                            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets\Fonts\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf#Open Sans"/>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="NavigationDrawerList" RowHeight="60"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="White"
                      ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding menuLista}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         Padding="20,10,0,10" Spacing="20">
                                <Image x:Name="ListviewMenuIcon" Source="{Binding IconSource}"
                                       WidthRequest="30"  HeightRequest="30" 
                                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       FontSize="Small"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       TextColor="#01426A">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans-Semibold"/>
                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="Calibri.ttf#Calibri"/>
                                            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets\Fonts\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf#Open Sans"/>
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage></ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Menu.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Menu : MasterDetailPage
{


    public ObservableCollection<MenuViewModel> _menuLista;

    public Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Settings.Page = "Menu";
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);


        _menuLista = ItemService.GetMenuItems();
        NavigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = _menuLista;



        Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Inicio_Menu)));

        if (Settings.InicioNavi < 2)
        {
            Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
        }

        var seconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.7);
        Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(seconds,
            () =>
            {
                CheckConnection();
                return true;
            });
    }

    public async void CheckConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)

            {
                Settings.InternetCon += 1;

                if (Settings.InternetCon < 2)
                {
                    await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new ConnectionActivityIndicator());
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (Settings.InternetCon > 0)
                {
                    Settings.InternetCon = 0;
                    await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
                    return;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    private async void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = (MenuViewModel)e.SelectedItem;

                //Obtem o tipo do objeto
                Type pagina = item.TargetType;

                Settings.Semana = "Current";
                Settings.day = "";

                string itemResult = item.IconSource;
                if (itemResult == "Logout.png")
                {
                    Settings.InicioNavi = 0;
                    Settings.Username = "";
                    CrossSecureStorage.Current.DeleteKey("LOGIN");
                    CrossSecureStorage.Current.DeleteKey("パスワード");
                    var vHomePage = new LoginUI();
                    Navigation.InsertPageBefore(vHomePage, this);
                    await Navigation.PopAsync();
                    IsPresented = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pagina));

                    IsPresented = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();

                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                {
                    XFToast.ShortMessage("Error");

                }


                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                {
                    ToastIOS.ShortIOSMessage("Error");

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                XFToast.ShortMessage("No Connection");

            }


            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                ToastIOS.ShortIOSMessage("No Connection");

            }

        }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using Mvvm ? or code behind

Comment: In this case the the .cs MenuViewModel contains the model.

Comment: Added more code to the question @Mina Fawzy.

Comment: 'Unselecting' is nothing else than selecting something else in the list... so generally you'll do 2 things in the Selected item event of the listview. 1. revert the previous selected item ( so change icon back to original ) 2. change the icon of the newly selected > so you need to keep track of previous selected item.

Comment: @Can you give a example with code?
thanks

Comment: I found a example with change colors of text in the selected cell in the listview, how can i translate this to changing a image?

https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/change-labels-textcolor-in-a-listviews-selecteditem-obviously-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: That is a good example... if you look at the setter of the SelectedItem, instead of doing _selectedItem.Selected = false; put your code to change the _selectedItem.IconImageSource = oldImageSource;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this example:

```
https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/change-labels-textcolor-in-a-listviews-selecteditem-obviously-in-xamarin-forms/
```

***This was the best solution that i came with.***

In the listview I create two images, one image with a source binding IconSelected and another to the IconUnSelected, both icons added to list used by the listview , and created a datatriger to each image to read the value converter by the IValueConverter, if the value is "IconSelected", the image with icon IconSelected is visible, if is "IconUnSelected" the image with icon IconUnSelected is visible.

My Listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="NavigationDrawerList" RowHeight="60"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="White"
                      ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding menuLista}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         Padding="20,10,0,10" Spacing="20">
                                <Image x:Name="ListIconSelected" Source="{Binding IconSelected}" IsVisible="False" IsEnabled="false" WidthRequest="30"  HeightRequest="30" 
                                       VerticalOptions="Center" >
                                    <Image.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Selected, Converter={StaticResource cnvInvert}}" Value="IconSelected">
                                            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Image.Triggers>
                                </Image>
                                <Image x:Name="ListIconUnSelected" IsEnabled="false" Source="{Binding IconUnSelected}" IsVisible="False" WidthRequest="30"  HeightRequest="30" 
                                       VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Image.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Selected, Converter={StaticResource cnvInvert}}" Value="IconUnSelected">
                                            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Image.Triggers>
                                </Image>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       FontSize="Small"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       TextColor="#01426A">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans-Semibold"/>
                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="Calibri.ttf#Calibri"/>
                                            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets\Fonts\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf#Open Sans"/>
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

IValueConverter:

```
public class SelectedToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter implementation

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((Boolean)value)
                return "IconSelected";
            else
                return "IconUnSelected";
        }
        return "IconUnSelected";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```